# I encountered some difficulties in using MyBatis, and the problem of fuzzy query passing in multiple parameters under mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

Thank you for checking my question.

Statements in mybatis have no results when making fuzzy queries, while command line execution in the database can query the results

When I replace the fields passed in by a fuzzy query with certain content, I can query and prove that mybatis supports passing parameters after the where condition.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzl9B.png)

Comment: You should not use images of code. Since It is difficult to reproduce that error through image. @清道夫

Answer (score -1):

select * from book_t where ${searchType} like concat('%',#{searchWord},'%')